# Performance. Is it useful to define my own exception types?

Tags: c#, .net, performance, exception

For example, I have a dll (`Helper.dll`) which contains some methods for working with external system through a provider library (`Provider.dll`). `Provider.dll` defines `SystemIsDownException` and I re-throw it in `Helper.dll`. Also, I have another dll (`Service.dll`) which uses `Helper.dll` and tons of others, it must catch different types of exceptions and process them somehow. My question is: does it really affect performance if I catch `SystemIsDownException` (from `Provider.dll`) in `Service.dll`? Or should I define my own exception types for each exception from `Provider.dll` in `Helper.dll`? Sorry for a long question.

Comment: Why do you think the *type* of exception thrown is going to affect performance?

Comment: What type of performance are you worried about? The loading of the assembly performance, or the actual throwing/handling of exceptions?

Comment: It simply doesn' t matter where the exception' s definition is. Once  .net framework bound to the dll that contains the definition, the exception' s type, where the dll is defined in do not matter.

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kcwalina/archive/2005/03/16/396787.aspx

Comment: I am worried about how many assemblies will be loaded into memory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do what you must do in logical terms, and don't care about performance.

Do not design exception types based in performance considerations. Create them if you find them meaningful and helpful to the helpfulness and clarity of your library.

Answer (score 2):

To answer your question in short: Do not catch and re-throw exceptions if you do not process the exceptions and add useful information. Just catching exceptions and then rethrowing them messes the stacktrace (for example when the original exception is lost) and of course it affects performance (as the runtime needs to prepare a stacktrace dumb). If you need to hide exceptions from the `provider.dll` if the `service.dll` cannot reference it, you'll need to rethrow them in the `helper.dll` (if you want to catch a specific exception from the `provider.dll` in the `service.dll`).

Answer (score 1):

Some ideas:

- The less wrapping code you write, the easier it'll be to maintain your code
- Don't use exceptions for logic control
- Exceptions have very little to do with performance, if you ask this question, you probably use it to control the logic

So the answer would be: define useful and meaningful exceptions that you need to (distinctively) handle. There is no performance hit, unless you use exceptions to direct logic flow, in which case you should stop and refactor your application.

Comment: Agreed.  Do NOT use for logic control.  Upvote.  This is also listed here:  http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kcwalina/archive/2005/03/16/396787.aspx